# Чи існує український аналог "бабайки"?

Tags: вживання-слів, етимологія, історія-мови

Згідно з [Вікіпедією](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9), `Бабай` - *нічний дух, уявна істота, згадування якої використовують батьки, щоб залякати неслухняних дітей. Бабай описується як «маленький дідусь з бородою і з торбинкою або великим мішком». Іноді Бабай не описується взагалі; в цьому випадку діти уявляють його самі.*

Слово походить, можливо, від тюркського «баба́».

Хоча лякати дітей погано, але чи існують аналоги цього "явища" українського походження?

Comment: Хм, я завжди вважав, що бабай — українське явище. Чи є якісь аргументи за те, що це не спільнослов'янське явище? Те, що слово (можливо) тюркського походження, ще не означає, що явище не українське (наприклад, воно могло закріпилося в мові давно, ще за часів монголо-татарської навали).

Comment: @Sasha у Вікіпедії "наприклад, в Середній Азії російські батьки лякають своїх дітей бабаєм, бабайкою, щоб ті скоріше заснули" ... Якщо це дійсно так, то можна зробити висновок, що явище не українське. Також є інформація, що у Полтавських селах років 40 тому про це й не чули

Comment: Як з фрази «в Середній Азії російські батьки лякають своїх дітей бабаєм» випливає, що українці не лякають своїх дітей бабаєм? «Також є інформація, що у Полтавських селах років 40 тому про це й не чули» — оце вже ближче, але Полтавщина — це ще не вся Україна (може, на Полтавщині не чули, а на Вінничині чули) — ну й джерела би. Пояснюю — я не стверджую, що бабай — притаманне українцям явище,  але й підтверджень протилежного я поки не чув.

Comment: > Як з фрази «в Середній Азії російські батьки лякають своїх дітей бабаєм» випливає, що українці не лякають своїх дітей бабаєм?
мав на увазі, "спільнослов'янське явище"

Comment: Мене мій дід лякав у дитинстві тим, що прийде жери́гімно, страшенна тварюка, гібрид крокодила та тигра. )))

Comment: А московити в XVII ст. лякали дітей, що прийде гетьман Сагайдачний. )))

Comment: [Звідси](http://www.poltavaforum.com/fleym-13/5381-strahi-ditinstva.html#post57286): «Цікаво, кого чим лякали в дитинстві?..» — «…, [Басаврюком](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Басаврюк), …».

Comment: @YellowSky "жери́гімно" :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На додачу до того, що я писав в [коментарі](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1319#comment3583_1319) (що я абсолютно не впевнений, що бабай є не українським):

- **Во́ва** — дитячий варіант слова «вовк».

  «Словарь української мови» Бориса Грінченка:

  > **[Во́ва](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/7794-vova.html#show_point)**, -ви, *ж.* Дѣтск. Волкъ: все страшное; бука, нелюдимъ. <…>

  [В інших словниках](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&scope=ukr&dicts=all&highlight=on).
- **Хо́ха**

  Словники:

  - «Словник української мови» в 11 томах:

    > **[ХО́ХА](http://sum.in.ua/s/khokha)**, и, *ж.* Міфічна істота, якою лякають дітей. <…>
  - «Словарь української мови» Бориса Грінченка:

    > **[Хо́ха](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/63190-khokha.html)**, -хи, *ж.* Страшилище, пугало, которымъ пугаютъ дѣтей. <…>
  - [Інші](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0&scope=ukr&dicts=all&highlight=on).

  Цитати:

  - [Вірш «Хоха» Галини Кирпи](http://abetka.ukrlife.org/kyrpa_poesia2.html).
  - > Мала прокинулась серед ночі і зіскочила з ліжечка. Вона шукала горщик, але, наштовхнувшись на нього в сутінках, від несподіванки закричала:
    >   — Хоха! — і обмочила штанці.
    >   Це змусило Русулю, старого біокібера, розплющити очі й устати до дитини.
    >   *<sub>//[Олександр Тесленко «Русуля», з книги «Атланти з планети Земля»](http://www.libros.am/book/read/id/170020/slug/atlanti-z-planeti-zemlya).</sub>*
  - > Хоха, яроха, забирай свій зуб, а як не будешь забирать, то буде тебе стрикаїл Михаїл сікти мечем, рубати, нечистий зуб забирати…
    >   *<sub>//[Замовляння у Поліссі, записане у с. Облітки від переселенця із с. Звіздаль](http://spadok.org.ua/polissya/zamovlyannya-v-systemi-duchovno-kultury-polissya).</sub>*

Answer (score 6):

Взагалі, Бабай хоча має тюркське походження, але значення "злий дух" — слов'янського походження. Вважається що таке значення слово отримало через те що татарами лякали дітей.

У татарські мові Бабай це просто "дідусь". Ще існує гіпотеза що Баба Яга також походить від "Бабай ага" — "старий пан".

Щодо інших міфологічні істот — їх багато (наприклад дідько), але страшне у Бабая це саме невизначеність його зовнішнього виду і що він з дітьми потім робить.